# Creating a Parquet file with PySpark on an AWS EMR cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I'm trying to spin up a Spark cluster with Datbricks' CSV package so that I can create parquet files and also do some stuff with Spark obviously.

This is being done within AWS EMR, so I don't think I'm putting these options in the correct place.

This is the command I want to send to the cluster as it spins up: `spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 --master yarn --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g`. I've tried putting this on a Spark step - is this correct?

If the cluster spun up without that being properly installed, how do I start up PySpark with that package? Is this correct: `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0`? I can't tell if it was installed properly or not. Not sure what functions to test

And in regards to actually using the package, is this correct for creating a parquet file:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false').load('s3n://bucketname/nation.tbl', schema = customSchema)

#is it this option1
df.write.parquet("s3n://bucketname/nation_parquet.parquet")

#or this option2
df.select('nation_id', 'name', 'some_int', 'comment').write.parquet('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('s3n://bucketname/nation_parquet.tbl')
```

I'm not able to find any recent (mid 2015 and later) documentation regarding writing a Parquet file.

Edit:

Okay, now I'm not sure if I'm creating my dataframe correctly. If I try to run some `select` queries on it and show the resultset, I don't get anything and instead some error. Here's what I tried running:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false').load('s3n://bucketname/nation.tbl', schema = customSchema)

df.registerTempTable("region2")

tcp_interactions = sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT nation_id, name, comment FROM region2 WHERE nation_id > 1 """)

tcp_interactions.show()
#get some weird Java error:
#Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0|ALGERIA|0| haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai|"
```